# Polymorphism between abstract class and its inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm a bit lost with the use of polymorphism: I have...
 - an abstract class A
 - a class B which inherits from A, implements its methods and adds some others
 - a class C which inherits from B and adds some more methods

I would like to be able to make a polymorphic use of this structure : create an object of class B, store it into a pointer to A, and call the methods from B on that pointer, without being able to call the methods from C on it.

Do I have to declare all the added methods from B and C in A and make them virtual, or is there another way? Wouldn't that be a problem if I create a B object, since at its level of inheritance there is still no definition of the methods from C?

Comment: If you store it into pointer to A, then you'll be able to call A methods only, unless you cast it back to pointer to B

Comment: Without virtual function declarations ([crtp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) not withstanding) there is no polymorphism here by definition. I.e. if you're asking how to access a non-virtual `B::memberfn()` without a polymorphic override of a similar `A::memberfn()`, using an `A* ptr;` without a vtable or a cast to a `B*` the answer is you can't.